# iPhone and ASIHTTPRequest - Https

Tags: ios, https, asihttprequest

Ok ,I know there are so ..so ..so many questions about this question,but no one can solve my question.
My iOS version is 6.1. I tried  HTTPS Connection to our server by mutually authenticating .But there is a error:

"A connection failure occurred: SSL problem (Possible causes may include a bad/expired/self-signed certificate, clock set to wrong date)";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-9807 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (OSStatus error -9807.)\""

Below is my code :

```
NSURL *httpsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://192.168.100.78"];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:httpsUrl];

SecIdentityRef identity = NULL;
SecTrustRef trust = NULL;


NSData *PKCS12Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myios" ofType:@"p12"]];

if (!PKCS12Data) {
    NSLog(@"certificate not found");
}

if (![self extractIdentity:&identity andTrust:&trust fromPKCS12Data:PKCS12Data]) {
    NSLog(@"NO");
    return;
};




[request setDelegate:self];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:20];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];



[request setClientCertificateIdentity:identity];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request startSynchronous];

NSError * error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"response is : %@",response);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[error userInfo]);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: ...and your question is? Are you using a self-signed cert? From the looks of the error, the CN of the SSL certificate does not match the domain that you are hitting.

Comment: Yes,I am using a self-signed cert. If I install the cert into my Mac and use safari to connect the url,no problem. But connect url via my app, it shows above error.

Comment: And the CN of the certificate is "192.168.100.78"?

Comment: Yes,client and server are in the same LAN.